# Crontab not registering changes by script

Tags: cron, subprocess, macos-sierra

I'm using python `subprocess` to make changes to `crontab`, specifically using:

```
subprocess.Popen(["crontab", cron_tab_file])
```

This all work fine and when I inspect the crontab using `crontab -l`, everything in the `cron_tab_file` is there. However, nothing runs.

I have always used full paths e.g.:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /full/path/to/test.sh
```

However, if I save the crontab again from terminal using `crontab -e` without actually changing anything, the crontab suddenly becomes active and starts to run the commands in it. I don't understand, shouldn't cron run by content in the crontab without needing manual updates? I'm using MacOS Sierra. This cron behavior troubles me and I can't find a solution or explanation anywhere online. I've made repeated tries and each time edits by python script doesn't work and if I change it by saving it manually it suddenly works.

Additional Information

I inspected `/usr/lib/cron/tabs` with sudo privilege, and my cron file are always changed  whether it's by me or by script. but if it were the script that changed it, then the change will not run. If I edited it manually, then message `crontab: installing new crontab` will show up and new commands will run. Is there a command to force cron to install new crontab?

Answer (score 0):

I have just discovered a very ugly work-around.

```
def activate_cron():
    execute = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "\033:wq\n"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    activate = subprocess.Popen(["crontab", "-e"], stdin=execute.stdout)
    # Wait for crontab to save
    time.sleep(5)
    activate.kill()
```

This will output `crontab: installing new crontab` and it will finally activate my minute tasks..